# iOS/macOS In app purchases - what to save in KeyChain

Tags: ios, swift, macos, in-app-purchase

I am implementing In app purchases for one of my apps which is cross platform (iOS + macOS). The way I implemented non-consumable IAP, is to save a flag in keychain for a specific key after the purchase was made. (e.g value `true` for the key `com.app.prodctId`) and just check at runtime if that flag exists and what the value is. However, this seems very insecure because some users might just add the key with the specific value in keychain, thus gaining acces to the locked feature without purchasing it. A solution to this would be to encrypt(or hash the data using a salt) the flag before saving it, but I would need to have a separate key for each iCloud account (so the user can enjoy the produc ton all devices across his iCloud account) and I am not really sure what this can be.

Is there anything that can be fetched per iCloud account so I can use as encryption key/salt for a hash? Or is there a better way to manage non-consumable in app purchases?

Comment: "because some users might just add the key with the specific value in keychain"  How would they do that?

Comment: On macOS, go to Keychain access, click "Create a new keychain item", and in there fill relevant informations.

Comment: Why not use the receipt provided by Apple?

Comment: If you save a key, a flag or whatever in the keychain programmatically, they won't be able to see it.  So what's the issue?

Comment: @PaulSchröder, I am not sure I understand the solution you propose. Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: @ElTomato, I am pretty sure you can see, edit and add everything you want from keychain.

Comment: What does that have to do with your iOS app or macOS application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every user downloading your app, Apple creates a receipt containing some meta-information (which app version the user downloaded, when, and so on).

When your app offers in-app purchases, those are also saved in the receipt. Since this receipt is automatically synced with all devices of the user, it is the right choice to check what a user bought and unlock the content on all of his devices correspondingly.

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/choosing_a_receipt_validation_technique) for an article from Apple about receipt validation techniques.
If you choose the local (on-device) receipt validation, I recommend you to use the [TPInAppReceipt](https://github.com/tikhop/TPInAppReceipt) library to encode the receipt. That saves a lot of headaches.